# Ubuntu 15.10 installation crash - caps lock blinking, then reboots

Tags: freeze

I have an MSI GT80 laptop. Trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on it via live usb (not using UEFI). However, intermittently during installation, it freezes, and after a brief period, the caps lock starts flashing on and off. 30 seconds later, it reboots. Would REALLY like to resolve this issue.

Does anybody know what this is, and if there's a workaround for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change to AHCI & removed RAID meta-data on SSD drives.

Comment: @kyodake, thanks for your reply. However, I'm unsure how do perform the things you mentioned. Is there any documentation available for those, or could you advise me how to do this?

Comment: go to: https://startpage.com/do/dsearch

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to update the BIOS, and it booted just fine (figures). I also had to run it with "nomodeset" before loading Ubuntu from a Live USB.